# Split cells in two and and form np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-itertools

```
list(itertools.product([[True,False],[False, True]], repeat=2))
```

The command above produces the output below.

```
[((True, False), (True, False)),
 ((True, False), (False, True)),
 ((False, True), (True, False)),
 ((False, True), (False, True))]
```

I want it however to look like this:

```
array([[ True, False, True, False],
       [ True, False, False, True],
       [False, True, True, False],
       [False, True, False, True]])
```

Anything will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First generate your product:

```
pr = list(itertools.product([[True, False], [False, True]], repeat=2))
```

Then convert it to a *Numpy* array, with proper reshaping:

```
a = np.array(pr).reshape((len(pr), -1))
```

The result is:

```
array([[ True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True]])
```

This code works also for other values of *repeat* (check e.g. for
*repeat=3*).

And a remark about other solutions: All of them, except for *mathfux*,
generate plain *pythonic* **lists**, not *Numpy* **arrays** (as you
specified).

Answer (score 0):

The values of the product list are tuples.

You can loop over the tuples of the product list,

each time concatenate each list's tuples to a new list:

e.g.

```
([True, False], [True, False]) -> [True, False, True, False]
```

***Option 1***

```
import itertools

x = list(itertools.product([[True,False],[False, True]], repeat=2))

x = [list(v[0] + v[1]) for v in x]

# [[True, False, True, False], [True, False, False, True], [False, True, True, False], [False, True, False, True]]
print(x)
```

***Option 2: One liner***

```
import itertools

x = [list(v[0] + v[1]) for v in list(itertools.product([[True,False],[False, True]], repeat=2))]

# [[True, False, True, False], [True, False, False, True], [False, True, True, False], [False, True, False, True]]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `numpy` terms, you need to change its shape:

```
X = [((True, False), (True, False)),
 ((True, False), (False, True)),
 ((False, True), (True, False)),
 ((False, True), (False, True))]
np.array(X).reshape(4,4)
[[ True False  True False]
 [ True False False  True]
 [False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = [[*a, *b] for a, b in itertools.product([[True,False],[False, True]], repeat=2)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[True, False, True, False], 
 [True, False, False, True],
 [False, True, True, False], 
 [False, True, False, True]]
```